# Block override for new order creation not working

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, overrides, session, language

I have created a simple module which adds an indicator to the store selection form when creating a new order from the backend.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYTLd.png)

As you can see it works, the problem is that it only works when you refresh this page, **it does not work when you load in this page for the first time**. (`Sales > Orders > Create new order > [Select customer]`)

This defeats the purpose of what I'm trying to do here, making a quick and simple indicator that shows which store the customer registered in.

I have rewritten the core block:

```
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Store_Select
```

adding these functions:

```
/**
* Retrieve quote session object
*
* @return Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Session_Quote
*/
protected function _getSession()
{
    return Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote');
}

/**
 * Retrieve customer model object
 *
 * @return Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
 */
protected function getCustomer()
{
    return $this->_getSession()->getCustomer();
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getCustomerCreatedIn()
{
    return $this->getCustomer()->getData('created_in');
}
```

So I can call `getCustomerCreatedIn()`in the template file:

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/create/store/select.phtml
```

`getCustomerCreatedIn()` is supposed to get the customer's registered language. but this returns null on the first call, on the second time it's getting called it does return a value. I think this is happening because the session for the customer's order isn't loaded in at that moment yet, only after completing the second page load? This is where I'm stuck.

Comment: Did you try to use Magento's log function to check what is being returned on the first call? Use `Mage::log()` to see what it returns.

Comment: I added `Mage::log($this->getCustomer()->getData('created_in'));` to the function: `getCustomerCreatedIn()`. the result I got was: 

6 times: `2017-01-23T14:20:16+00:00 DEBUG (7): `

6 times: `2017-01-23T14:21:30+00:00 DEBUG (7): English`

Comment: So you get an empty result the first time?

Comment: I indeed get an empty result the first time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Superficial answer:** you cannot.
When creating an order in the backend, the list of the stores is generated at the same time as the customer list is.

[image: Note the display:none for the stores block]

The click on the customer row triggers an Ajax call which updates the headline of the page and toggle the stores list visibility.
That's why the customer doesn't exist in the session the first time the stores list is generated: because it has not been selected yet.

**Alternative answer:** you can hook to the javascript responsible for the stores list visibility and update the list via Ajax (that's just an idea).

[image: hook to rowClickCallback]

Here is a working example:

**Override Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Customer_Grid** and redefine a custom getAdditionalJavaScript method. This method is called by the adminhtml/template/widget/grid.phtml template file.

```
<?php

class Ep_Customerstore_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Create_Customer_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Customer_Grid {

    public function getAdditionalJavaScript() {
        $js = '
        AdminOrder.prototype.setCustomerAfter = function () {
        this.customerSelectorHide();

        if (this.storeId) {
            $(this.getAreaId(\'data\')).callback = \'dataLoaded\';
            this.loadArea([\'data\'], true);
        }
        else {
            this.storeSelectorShow();

            /* Here starts our custom code.
             The selected customer id stored in the variable this.customerId
             So, starting from the customer Id you can perform an Ajax call which resolve its registration store Id.
            */

           new Ajax.Request(\''. Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("adminhtml/customerstore_ajax/get") .'\',{
            method:\'POST\',
            parameters: {id: this.customerId},
            requestHeaders: {Accept: \'application/json\'},
            onSuccess:function(transport){
                var response = transport.responseText.evalJSON(true);

                /* 
                Now you can modify the look of the store label by adding your custom content
                */
                $$(\'label[for="store_\'+ response["store_id"] + \'"]\').each(function(el) {
                    el.insert(\' <strong>Customer registered here</strong>\');
                });
            }.bind(this)
            });
        }

    };';
        return $js;
    }
}
```

**Then create your controller to serve the Ajax call**

```
<?php

class Ep_Customerstore_Adminhtml_Customerstore_AjaxController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_action {
    public function getAction() {
        $id     = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $customer  = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($id);
        if($customer) {
            $storeId = $customer->getData('store_id');
        } else {
            $storeId = 0;
        }

        $responseArray = array('store_id' => $storeId);

        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($responseArray));
    }
}
```

And here's the result you'd get

[image]

For completeness, here you can find the working module:
https://github.com/eperrotta/Ep_Customerstore

Comment: can you explain further on this approach?

Comment: I added a basic sample of working code

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you should try using an event observer.

In your module's `config.xml` add the following:

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <core_layout_block_create_after>
            <observers>
                <my_custom_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>module/observer</class>
                    <method>blockCreateAfter</method>
                </my_custom_observer>
            </observers>
        </core_layout_block_create_after>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

Where `module` is the name you used for your models, declared like this in the `config.xml`

```
<global>
    <models>
        <module>
            <class>Vendor_Module_Model</class>
        </module>
    </model>
</global>
```

Then in `Model\Observer.php` :

```
<?php

class Vendor_Module_Model_Observer {

    public function blockCreateAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $block = $observer->getBlock();
        if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Store_Select) {
            $block->setCustomerCreatedIn($this->getCustomerCreatedIn());
        }
    }

    protected function getCustomerCreatedIn()
    {
        return $this->getCustomer()->getData('created_in');
    }

    protected function getCustomer()
    {
         return $this->_getSession()->getCustomer();
    }

    protected function _getSession()
    {
         return Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote');
    }

}
```

With this observer, you should be able to call `$this->getCustomerCreatedIn()` in your template.

Comment: I am with you bro , as we have event and observers for this why anyone override the classes

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala probably because they're not aware of it. I've been overriding classes for years because I understood the event/observer system and started using it

Comment: great to learn about observers in magento, but this is not the solution. this still leaves the returned value of `getCustomerCreatedIn()` empty on the first page load.